# What is the biggest fivedigit $abcde$ number, thats divisible by $bcde$, $cde$, $de$ and $e$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

What is the biggest fivedigit $abcde$ number, thats divisible by $bcde$, $cde$, $de$ and $e$?

I was trying to find it but I couldnt. Can you help me with a step by step answer?

Comment: Why don't you show us what you tried (edit your post and add that information). We can help you best, that way. Perhaps you were on the right track, save for a mistake along the way.

Comment: Have you solved the problem for two/three/four digit numbers? Does that give you an idea?

Comment: Can anyone confirm if there is a mathematical notation for representation of a number's decimal digits by using variables? I am pretty sure there is, but can't remember it...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If $bcde$ divides $abcde$, it also divides $a0000$, or $a*2^4*5^4$.  But since $e$ divides $abcde$, $e$ must not be zero, so $bcde$ is not divisible by $10$.  So $bcde$ can have factors of $2$ or $5$ but not both, so it divides either $a*2^4$ or $a * 5^4$.  The maximum value $bcde$ could be then is $9*5^4 = 5625$, which means $abcde$ would be $95625$.  One can check that this works.

Comment: That is really nice!

Comment: Much better than my way which was to write a quick program to count down from 99999 and check each result until I found a solution. 95625 is indeed the largest solution.

Comment: I wrote the program too, and was surprised to find that there were so many solutions (119 five-digit numbers have this property). But after seeing this answer, I was no longer surprised, and the pattern, which had seemed obscure, was obvious.

Comment: Here is my [checker](https://gist.github.com/0472dcf4870e76e70950) and its [output](https://gist.github.com/f50e7315e084b9cc26c2).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It was really simple and understandable.

Comment: I immediately jumped to brute-forcing this too (in Haskell): https://gist.github.com/purcell/d95c237ed297f4168bbc